# What means closure after init?

Tags: swift, syntax

Xcode playground game boilerplate generates the code, with the class:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
 // no init override here
}
```

then instantiating the class:

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

    // Present the scene
    sceneView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

I searched documentation and there is no `init` with trailing closure. Neither any `init` defined in `GameScene`. So what is the closure after `GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a closure, but optional binding. The `GameScene(fileNamed:)` is a failable initializer, so might return `nil`. The `if let` optional binds the return value, meaning that the `if` branch is hit in case the return value was not `nil` and inside the `if` statement, `scene` is guaranteed to be non-nil.

For more information, see the [Optional Binding](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) section of the Swift Language Guide.